# When DEBUG signal gets delivered in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I need a command to be executed before shell starts to execute the user passed command,so as many sites suggested i tried using trap with DEBUG signal, but that did not happen.

I registered following trap in `/etc/profile`:

```
trap 'echo "my_command"' DEBUG
```

Whats happening now is :

```
sw0:root:root> pwd

/root

my_command

sw0:root:root>
```

What i want is(As per manual definition)

```
sw0:root:root> pwd

my_command

/root

sw0:root:root>
```

Bash version used:

`GNU bash, version 2.04.0(1)-release (powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu)`

Please Clarify my following doubt

When do i get the DEBUG signal,before executing every command (or) after executing every command?

I want my command to be executed before shell executes the every command passed by user, Please help me on this.

Comment: If you use `sleep` instead of `echo` which order do the `sleep` and `pwd` happen in? Could this be an output flushing problem? Also that bash version is **ancient**.

Comment: Etan i tried sleep result was same,i believe its because of ancient version.Could you please let me know is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You saw the output of `pwd` and then the sleep waited? I suppose it is possible the `DEBUG` hook worked differently in that version. Huh, and indeed it did. The change to running before the command happened in bash-2.05a-release according to the changelog. So the way to achieve this is to upgrade. What system is this with such an ancient version?